# How does expectation maximization compute missing data?

Tags: r, expectation-maximization

I have been searching for a simple example of how expectation-maximization (EM) computes missing data. All the examples I have found are based on [multivariate normal models](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3909980/understanding-how-em-algorithm-actually-works-for-missing-data). I have seen that EM can be applied to any probability distribution, but I cannot find a good tutorial using R on how to apply EM to say count data. If I have a response variable y with NAs and a predictor variable x, what are the steps involved in applying EM to estimating the missing values if y is negative binomially distributed?

```
## Simulate data
library("MASS")
set.seed(123)
n       <- 1000
theta   <- 20
beta0   <- 3
beta1   <- 0.2
x       <- runif(n=n, min=1, max=10)
mu      <- exp(beta0 + beta1 * x)
y       <- rnegbin(n=n, mu=mu, theta=theta)
data    <- data.frame(x=x, y=y)
data$y[which(y %in% sample(y, 100))] <- NA
plot(data$x, data$y)
```

Also, are there any R packages for applying EM to data with probability distributions other than Gaussian?

Comment: 1) EM works the same way, no matter what the distribution. The exact form of the E and M steps will differ but, conceptually, it's the same calculation (i.e. find the expected log likelihood and then maximize it). Where exactly are you getting stuck? 2) Missing values can only be inferred if the observed values provide some information about them. This means you'll need a multivariate/joint distribution that captures dependencies between the observed and missing values. A negative binomial distribution won't work because it only models a single count variable.

Comment: Gotcha,  I have modified my question to be more informative. I am getting stuck with translating the maths from here (https://cswr.nrhstat.org/em.html) into something I can understand using a coding example that is not Gaussian.

Comment: Are any of $\theta$, $\beta_0$, and $\beta_1$ known? Will the EM use the same data model as what was used to generate the data?

Comment: Apologies, all the parameters are unknown and EM would ideally use the same generating model as the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be quite right--the final value for $\theta$ is too large (meaning the variance is too small) because the expected value is used to impute the missing data. However, the initial estimate for $\theta$ is quite close. Maybe someone else can chime in about how to do this differently.

```
library("MASS")
set.seed(123)
n     <- 1000
theta <- 20
beta0 <- 3
beta1 <- 0.2
x     <- runif(n=n, min=1, max=10)
mu    <- exp(beta0 + beta1*x)
y     <- rnegbin(n=n, mu=mu, theta=theta)
idxm  <- which(y %in% sample(y, 100))
y0    <- y[-idxm]
x0    <- x[-idxm]
logy0 <- log(y0)

# initialize parameter values
betaInit  <- unname(lm(logy0 ~ x0)$coefficients)
mu0       <- exp(betaInit[1] + betaInit[2]*x0)
thetaInit <- mean(mu0^2/(mean((mu0 - y0)^2) - mu0))
params1   <- c(thetaInit, betaInit)
params0   <- numeric(3)

# initialize unobserved values
y[idxm] <- as.integer(exp(params1[2] + params1[3]*x[idxm]))

# negative log-likelihood
fNLL <- function(params) {
  -sum(dnbinom(y, params[1], mu = exp(params[2] + params[3]*x), log = TRUE))
}

# iteratively find MLE on imputed data and then re-impute data
while (max(abs(params1 - params0)) > 1e-9) {
  params1 <- optim(params0 <- params1, fNLL, lower = 0, method = "L-BFGS-B")$par
  y[idxm] <- as.integer(exp(params1[2] + params1[3]*x[idxm]))
}
```