# Manually program EM in r to updated multiple parameters and solve missing data

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, data-imputation, expectation-maximization

I am trying to use EM (Expectation-maximization) to fill in missing data in R, but am not sure how to model/code it for my specific case. I am generally trying to follow the example format used in this post ([How does expectation maximization compute missing data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/564630/how-does-expectation-maximization-compute-missing-data)), with the following structure of the EM process:

```
library("MASS")
set.seed(123)
n     <- 1000
theta <- 20
beta0 <- 3
beta1 <- 0.2
x     <- runif(n=n, min=1, max=10)
mu    <- exp(beta0 + beta1*x)
y     <- rnegbin(n=n, mu=mu, theta=theta)
idxm  <- which(y %in% sample(y, 100))
y0    <- y[-idxm]
x0    <- x[-idxm]
logy0 <- log(y0)

# initialize parameter values
betaInit  <- unname(lm(logy0 ~ x0)$coefficients)
mu0       <- exp(betaInit[1] + betaInit[2]*x0)
thetaInit <- mean(mu0^2/(mean((mu0 - y0)^2) - mu0))
params1   <- c(thetaInit, betaInit)
params0   <- numeric(3)

# initialize unobserved values
y[idxm] <- as.integer(exp(params1[2] + params1[3]*x[idxm]))

# negative log-likelihood
fNLL <- function(params) {
  -sum(dnbinom(y, params[1], mu = exp(params[2] + params[3]*x), log = TRUE))
}

# iteratively find MLE on imputed data and then re-impute data
while (max(abs(params1 - params0)) > 1e-9) {
  params1 <- optim(params0 <- params1, fNLL, lower = 0, method = "L-BFGS-B")$par
  y[idxm] <- as.integer(exp(params1[2] + params1[3]*x[idxm]))
}
```

However, in my case, my data is a bit different. I am trying to fill in missingness in 2 variables (x1 and x2) that will be predictors (betas) in my regression. I do not know the parameters of the complete data for x1 and x2, but I do have complete data for x3, x4, and x5, all additional predictive variables in the regression model I will ultimately run with the complete data. My ultimate regression is very simple and looks like the following:

```
model = lm(data, y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5)
```

How can I iteratively update both x1 and x2 using EM to fill in their missingness, similar to the above example? Do I need to use information from x3 x4 and x5 (like multiple imputation?) or can I use a simple EM algorithm with the above and update x1 and x2 simultaneously? In my case, I do not have complete data (as this does